# Sub-sampling by ID and Day

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a large data set that I want to sub-sample. My goal is to have one measurement (X) for each individual (ID) per day (datetime).

My original df looks like this:

```
    > df
     ID        X            datetime
555 287 450767.0 2018-03-02 15:00:00
556 287 450769.4 2018-03-02 18:00:00
557 287 450672.8 2018-03-03 00:00:00
558 287 450686.0 2018-03-03 03:00:00
559 287 450678.9 2018-03-03 09:00:00
560 287 450678.9 2018-03-03 12:00:00
561 287 450277.6 2018-03-03 21:00:00
562 287 450255.8 2018-03-04 00:00:00
563 287 450916.5 2018-03-04 21:00:00
564 287 450802.1 2018-03-05 21:00:00
565 287 450780.0 2018-03-06 00:00:00
566 287 451074.5 2018-03-06 21:00:00
567 287 450279.3 2018-03-07 00:00:00
568 287 450899.6 2018-03-07 21:00:00
569 287 450685.7 2018-03-03 03:00:00
570 287 450678.6 2018-03-03 09:00:00
571 287 450678.6 2018-03-03 12:00:00
572 287 450277.6 2018-03-03 21:00:00
573 287 450255.8 2018-03-04 00:00:00
574 287 450916.5 2018-03-04 21:00:00
575 287 450802.4 2018-03-05 21:00:00
576 287 450780.0 2018-03-06 00:00:00
577 287 451074.8 2018-03-06 21:00:00
578 287 450279.1 2018-03-07 00:00:00
805  41 450911.1 2018-03-07 12:00:00
806  41 450891.1 2018-03-07 15:00:00
807  41 450883.9 2018-03-07 18:00:00
```

I have tried the following:

```
df.thin<-df %>% group_by(ID) %>% group_by(day=floor_date(datetime, "day")) %>% sample_n(size = 1)
```

However this results in one measurement per day and not  one measurement for each individual per day.

EX:

```
  > df.thin
    # A tibble: 6 x 4
    # Groups:   day [6]
      ID          X datetime            day                
      <fct>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
    1 287   450767. 2018-03-02 15:00:00 2018-03-02 00:00:00
    2 287   450673. 2018-03-03 00:00:00 2018-03-03 00:00:00
    3 287   450916. 2018-03-04 21:00:00 2018-03-04 00:00:00
    4 287   450802. 2018-03-05 21:00:00 2018-03-05 00:00:00
    5 287   451075. 2018-03-06 21:00:00 2018-03-06 00:00:00
    6 41    450891. 2018-03-07 15:00:00 2018-03-07 00:00:00
```

My goal is the following:

```
> df.thin.goal
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   day [6]
  ID          X datetime            day                
  <fct>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 287   450769. 2018-03-02 18:00:00 2018-03-02 00:00:00
2 287   450686. 2018-03-03 03:00:00 2018-03-03 00:00:00
3 287   450916. 2018-03-04 21:00:00 2018-03-04 00:00:00
4 287   450802. 2018-03-05 21:00:00 2018-03-05 00:00:00
5 287   451075. 2018-03-06 21:00:00 2018-03-06 00:00:00
6 287   450279. 2018-03-07 00:00:00 2018-03-07 00:00:00
7 41    450884. 2018-03-07 18:00:00 2018-03-07 00:00:00
```

Comment: I think you mean `group_by(ID, day=floor_date(datetime, "day"))`. A new `group_by` overwrites any prior grouping.

Comment: If the first column in your df is the row number, you have duplicates in. The sequence of grouping variables may also have an influence on your result. If you want to calculate time differences for instance, this will give different results.

Answer (score 0):

You can give more than one argument to group_by(), which will group by more than one grouping variable hierarchically. That should solve your problem:

```
  df.thin<-df %>% 
  group_by(ID, day=floor_date(datetime, "day")) %>% 
  sample_n(size = 1)
```

Result:

```
> df.thin
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   ID, day [7]
     ID       X datetime            day                
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1    41 450884. 2018-03-07 18:00:00 2018-03-07 00:00:00
2   287 450767  2018-03-02 15:00:00 2018-03-02 00:00:00
3   287 450278. 2018-03-03 21:00:00 2018-03-03 00:00:00
4   287 450256. 2018-03-04 00:00:00 2018-03-04 00:00:00
5   287 450802. 2018-03-05 21:00:00 2018-03-05 00:00:00
6   287 451075. 2018-03-06 21:00:00 2018-03-06 00:00:00
7   287 450900. 2018-03-07 21:00:00 2018-03-07 00:00:00
```